# Regex pattern within text

Tags: python, regex

I have a long string of data which looks like:

```
dstgfsda12345.123gsrsvrvsdfcsd23456.234tsrsd
```

Notice that the '12345.123' pattern is the same. I want to split the string on it using python (so `s.split(<regex>)`).

What would be the appropriate regex?

```
'[0-9]{5}.[0-9]{3}'
```

does not work; I presume it expects whitespace around it(?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just escape `.`, and you are done:

```
\d{5}\.\d{3}
```

You can use Regex token `\d` as a shorthand for `[0-9]`.

**Example:**

```
>>> re.split(r'\d{5}\.\d{3}', 'dstgfsda12345.123gsrsvrvsdfcsd23456.234tsrsd')
['dstgfsda', 'gsrsvrvsdfcsd', 'tsrsd']
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand exactly what's your actual need but seems that you want your regex to isolate each occurrence of 5 digits, dot, 3 digits.

So instead of `'[0-9]{5}.[0-9]{3}'` you must use `'[0-9]{5}\.[0-9]{3}'`, because `.` matches any character, while `\.` matches only a dot.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex should be `'\d{5}\.\d{3}'`.

Check the usage of `.` instead of `\.`. That is because, '.' (Dot.) in the default mode, matches any character except a newline. Refer [regex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) document. Whereas `\s` means `dot` in your string.

For example:

```
import re
my_string = 'dstgfsda12345.123gsrsvrvsdfcsd23456.234tsrsd'
my_regex = '\d{5}\.\d{3}'
re.split(my_regex, my_string)
# returns: ['dstgfsda', 'gsrsvrvsdfcsd', 'tsrsd']
```

**Explanation** on how `'\d{5}\.\d{3}'` works:

`\d` means any digit between `0-9`. `\d{5}` sub-string with any 5 consecutive digits. `\.` means digits followed by single `.`. At last `\d{3}` means any 3 digits after `.`